# Personal builds with Hudson continuous integration server

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I'm thinking of using Hudson as my continuous integration server. In the past i have used the Pulse build server from Zutubi which had a nice feature called personal builds that allows a user to test a changelist on the Pulse server before committing the code. Does anyone know if Hudson offers this as either a built in feature or via a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers on other questions on stackoverflow, there might be a way to emulate this feature with git and Hudson. Don't know if that might be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes using GIT seems to be the only way to perform what i require currently.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Pulse for a while and that's one of the things I'm missing. I don't think hudson does that.